# Can't compare clist item with string

Tags: latex3, strings, catcodes, comma-separated-list, compare

I can't compare `comma list item` with `string`. `\clist_a` is a temp var.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \clist_a
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
    key .code:n      = {\clist_gput_right:Nn \clist_a { #1 }},
    key .default:n   = World
}
\keys_set:nn { mymodule }
{
    key = Fred, % Prints ’Hello Fred’
    key = Amy,
    key = Tom,
} 
\clist_use:Nn \clist_a {~and~}\par

%%% Example doesn't work
\str_case:nnF {\clist_item:Nn \clist_a{1}}{
    {Fred} {Fred~in~This~Clist}
}{Doesn't~Found~Fit}\par
\str_if_eq:nnTF {\clist_item:Nn \clist_a{1}}{Fred}{Equal}{Not~equal}\par

%%% working Example
\clist_if_in:NnTF \clist_a{Fred}{in}{Not~in}\par

\clist_map_inline:Nn \clist_a {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1}{Amy}
        {\clist_map_break:}
        {\#1~is~#1\par}
} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The problem is that:

- the `\str_case:nnF` can't find the match string `Fred`
- why do the last 2 example `\clist_map_inline:Nn` and `\clist_if_in:NnTF` work, but the first and second example doesn't work?

I read the following about the `clist` in `interface3`:

> **TEXhackers note**: The result is returned within the \unexpanded primitive (\exp_not:n),
> which means that the ⟨item⟩ does not expand further when appearing in an x-type argument
> expansion.

I guess the reasons may be

- `catcode` of the item in clist
- something about `expansion`?

Comment: Why not use the provided scratch/temp variables `\g_tmpa_clist` and `\g_tmpb_clist`?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I won't ignore `\clist_a`, which is a bad name, scratch variable or not. Stick with the naming scheme.

With

```
\str_case:nnF {\clist_item:Nn \g_zang_temp_clist {1}}
  {
   {Fred{Fred~in~This~Clist}
  }
  {false}
```

you ask LaTeX to compare the *literal string*

```
\clist_item:Nn \g_zang_temp_clist {1}
```

(all characters with category code 12) with the string `Fred`. Obviously there is no match.

What you want is to expand the first argument in order to deliver the actual item stored in the `clist`. What is the TeXhackers note telling us? That if you have

```
\clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\bfseries a}
```

and this is the first item, then when `\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1}` is subject to `e`-expansion (or `x`-expansion), the item will be returned as `\bfseries a`, that is, no control sequence will be further expanded.

Thus the correct way to string-compare the item in the `clist` with a given string is to use a suitable `e` variant:

```
\str_if_eq:eeTF {\clist_item:Nn \g_zang_temp_clist {1}}{Fred}{equal}{not~equal}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_zang_temp_clist

\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
    key .code:n      = {\clist_gput_right:Nn \g_zang_temp_clist { #1 }},
    key .default:n   = World,
}
\keys_set:nn { mymodule }
{
    key = Fred, % Prints ’Hello Fred’
    key = Amy,
    key = Tom,
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%%% Example works
\str_case:enF {\clist_item:Nn \g_zang_temp_clist{1}}
 {
  {Fred}{Fred~in~This~Clist}
 }
 {Doesn't~Found~Fit}

\par

\str_if_eq:eeTF {\clist_item:Nn \g_zang_temp_clist {1}}{Fred}{Equal}{Not~equal}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

You find the predefined variants in `interface3.pdf`, but you can define your own if necessary with `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`.

Answer (score 4):

All the `\str_if_eq:` family functions are based on `\__str_if_eq:nn`, which will expand to `0` as an explicit character with category 12 if the two lists match (and either `-1` or `1` if they don’t).

From `source3.pdf`, we can find the definitions of `\str_if_eq:nn` and `\str_if_eq:ee`:

```
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \str_if_eq:nn #1#2 { p , T , F , TF }
  {
    \if:w 0 \__str_if_eq:nn { \exp_not:n {#1} } { \exp_not:n {#2} }
      \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \str_if_eq:ee #1#2 { p , T , F , TF }
  {
    \if:w 0 \__str_if_eq:nn {#1} {#2}
      \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
  }
```

The only difference is that `\str_if_eq:nn` compares two strings without expanding them. See the following test for example:

```
\str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { hello }
\str_if_eq_p:nn { hello } { \l_tmpa_str } % returns false
\str_if_eq_p:ee { hello } { \l_tmpa_str } % returns true
```

Answer (score 2):

The example works with `\str_case:enF` and `\str_if_eq:enTF`. This is because `\clist_item:Nn \clist_a{1}` needs to be expanded first.

This is not necessary with `\clist_if_in:NnTF \clist_a{Fred}{in}{Not~in}` because `Fred` does not need to be expanded. It is also not necessary with `\str_if_eq:nnTF {#1}{Amy}` because `#1` also does not need to be expanded.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{expl3}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { enF }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_if_eq:nnTF { enTF }
\clist_new:N \clist_a
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
    key .code:n      = {\clist_gput_right:Nn \clist_a { #1 }},
    key .default:n   = World
}
\keys_set:nn { mymodule }
{
    key = Fred, % Prints ’Hello Fred’
    key = Amy,
    key = Tom,
} 
\clist_use:Nn \clist_a {~and~}\par

%%% Example did not work, but does now
\str_case:enF {\clist_item:Nn \clist_a{1}}{
    {Fred} {Fred~in~This~Clist}
}{Doesn't~Found~Fit}\par
\str_if_eq:enTF {\clist_item:Nn \clist_a{1}}{Fred}{Equal}{Not~equal}\par

%%% working Example
\clist_if_in:NnTF \clist_a{Fred}{in}{Not~in}\par

\clist_map_inline:Nn \clist_a {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1}{Amy}
        {\clist_map_break:}
        {\#1~is~#1\par}
} 
\end{document}
```